# Can't start Unity: blank screen with flashing cursor. PCIe Bus Error

Tags: 16.04, unity, lightdm

I am completely new to Ubuntu. My system, which is 3 days old is not allowing me to launch unity. Up until now I have needed to run

```
 sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service
```

To launch it. This morning during a computationally intensive run of deeplearning my system crashed (everything froze and I needed to do a hard reboot). Since then, when I try to launch Unity I get a blank screen with a flashing cursor.

I ran

```
 exec sudo -i
```

and tried this

[is there a command to factory reset Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859448/is-there-a-command-to-factory-reset-ubuntu)

I have reinstalled lightdm, unity and ubuntu-desktop.

I also tried this

[(13.04) lightdm crashing - black screen flashing cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346738/13-04-lightdm-crashing-black-screen-flashing-cursor)

and have tried this

[Ownership of .Xauthority transferred to root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436925/ownership-of-xauthority-transferred-to-root)

Nothing is working, however I am getting this error message:

```
 [331.322881] pcieport 0000:00:02.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity-Corrected, type=Data Link Layer, id=0010(Receiver ID)
 [331.323119] pcieport 0000:00:02.0: DEVICE [8086:6F04] error status/mask=00000080/00002000
 [331.323119] pcieport 0000:00:02.0: [7] Bad DLLP
```

I have no idea what this means or how to debug it. Could someone offer some guidance please.

Answer (score 0):

Having to manually restart lightdm is not normal. Especially for a new Ubuntu installation.

First I'd recommend checking that you have the latest BIOS installed for your motherboard, and the latest firmware and drivers for your Nvidia/GPU video card.

The PCIe error is your GPU. If you have multiple GPU's, you may need to test one GPU at a time, to eliminate a single failure or seating problem.

If firmware and drivers don't fix the problem, you may need to add kernel boot time options to cure it. Please see https://forums.lime-technology.com/topic/50821-solved-logs-filling-up-with-aerpcie-bus-errors/ for one example.

A Google search for "device id 8086:6F04" will give you more information.